# Cannot add esri leaflet tiled layer with proxy

Tags: proxy, leaflet, layer, esri

I need to add dynamic and tiled layers to map using proxy. 
I use the following code:

```
  var tiled = L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
        url: 
  "https://<domain>/arcgs/rest/services/basemaps/<name1>/MapServer"
        ,            
        proxy: 'proxy/proxy.ashx',
        useCors:false
    }).addTo(map);

    var gasStations = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
        url: 
    "https://<domain>/arcgs/rest/services/dynamic/gas_stations/MapServer"
       ,
        proxy: 'proxy/proxy.ashx',
        useCors: false
    }).addTo(map);
```

The dynamic layer is added to the map, but the tiled layer not and I get many messages in console of the following type:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 499 ()

<domain>/arcgs/rest/services/basemaps/<name1>/MapServer/tile/<level>/<x>/<y>
```

When I click on one of these links I get in new page:

```
HTTP Status 499 - Token Required
```

So I think that the problem is in proxy but  I don't understand why it works for dynamic layer and does not work for tiled cached layer.

Comment: This means the tiled layer needs your credentials.. please see if you can pass username and password in the header or some other format...

Comment: Yes, I pass username and password, but this does not help